Weierstrass' definition of Gamma function and Euler-Mascheroni constant
Recently came to know about Weierstrass' definition of Gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ and Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = z e^{\gamma z} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \left(1+ \frac{z}{n}\right) e^{-z /n} \right)$$
so if $z= 1$ does $$2 e^{2 \gamma} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right) e^{-2 /n} \right) = 1?$$
If so, how?

\begin{eqnarray*}
 e^{ \gamma} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( \left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \right) &=& \lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma} \prod_{n=1}^N \left( \left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \right)\\
&=&\lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma}\prod_{n=1}^N \left( \frac{n+1}{n} e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \right)\\
&=&\lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma} \left[\frac{2}{1}\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}\cdots \frac{N+1}{N} \right]e^{-\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=&\lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma} (N+1)e^{-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=& \lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma} e^{\ln(N+1)}e^{-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=&  e^{ \gamma} \left(e^{\ln(N+1)}e^{-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n}}\right)e^{\frac{1}{N+1}}\\
&=&   e^{ \gamma} \left(e^{ \lim_{N\to \infty}-\left(-\ln(N+1)+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right) \lim_{N\to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{N+1}}\\
&=& \lim_{N\to \infty}  e^{ \gamma} e^{-\gamma} \lim_{N\to \infty}e^{\frac{1}{N+1}}\\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Could you explain the second last step please?

Sure, since $e^x$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ $ \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)}$

How does that equal to $e^{-\gamma}$ in the second last step?

@JayadrataBanerjee Hi, that was due to the definition of the Euler's constant
$$\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\log n + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}\right)$$

Thanks a lot for the clear explanation
